# C static inline parameter evaluation optimization

Tags: c, optimization, language-lawyer

Assume an API in which every function returns an error code which is zero in case of no error and nonzero for error values.

Let

```
int foo(...);
int bar(...);
```

be functions in this API. Let there be a code fragment in which `foo` and `bar` have to be called in order *and foo and bar should **always** be called, regardless of previous error* but the first returned nonzero error code is to be propagated, i.e.

```
int foobar(...)
{
    int rc = 0, rc_;
    /* ... */
    rc_ = foo(...); rc = rc ? rc : rc_;
    rc_ = bar(...); rc = rc ? rc : rc_;
    return rc;
}
```

Writing the rc,rc_ multiplexing is tiring and error prone (no matter if a ternary operator, if/else or something else is used).

Let there be an error propagating helper function

```
static inline
int rc_propagate(int r, int p){ return p ? p : r; }
```

This could be used in `foobar` like this

```
int foobar(...)
{
    int rc = 0;
    /* ... */
    rc = rc_propagate(foo(...), rc);
    rc = rc_propagate(bar(...), rc);
    return rc;
}
```

Does the C standard allow to optimize by pulling the evaluation of the first parameter of `rc_propagate`, a static inline function, into the ternary so that it may not get executed due to the ternary operator evaluation rules if the second parameter `p` were nonzero?

Comment: I think no, but I'll wait for someone to quote the relevant part of the standard.

Comment: @2501: Only that in this case it's not an external function, but static inline. My doubts are solely about static inline; specifically I've just read a few blog entries of the LLVM developers and possible optimizations regarding calling functions that are static inline.

Comment: On a side note, why don't you just write:  `rc = rc ? rc : foo(...);`  and avoid the issue altogether?

Comment: I think that because the function call to `bar()` is an argument to the inline function, it must be called even if `foo()` failed — which is not what you want.  The behaviour of the program shouldn't change whether the function `rc_propagate()` is inline or not.

Comment: If you *want* it to be evaluated regardless, I think the inline function will do that.  If not, you could try a function-like macro...

Comment: Do you want to call *all* the functions but just keep the first error return value, or do you just want to call the functions up to the first one that fails and skip the rest?

Comment: Does the function have sideeffects?

Comment: @2501: Because I want foo and bar to be executed at all times.

Comment: @Dmitri: I want all the functions to be called regardless of error state.

Comment: @datenwolf I understand, I though you didn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Because I don't want them to short circuit. They should all execute, but if one of them fails, the first error code should be returned. Technically it would be nice to return a whole list of error codes if several functions fail in order, but error lists involve additional complexity and usually the first error in a chain is telling enough; why insist on calling the rest of the functions: Let them be part of cleanup code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compiler(or hardware for that matter) is allowed to optimize the program<sup>1</sup> as long as the program stays the same, i.e. you cannot prove that the program that was executed was different from the one you wrote.

In this case the program you wrote will always call the external function because it isn't present in the ternary operator where it may not be evaluated. The function may have different interesting side-effects and is unknown to the compiler. This means that the optimized version of the program will have to call the external function at some point (code may be reordered) to preserve that behavior.

If that weren't true you could prove that the program that was executed wasn't the same as the one you wrote. Doing this would be easy; put a printf(or equivalent) statement into the external function call.

<sub>1. A concept of an abstract program which exists when it is executing, not the generated machine code or executable.</sub>

---

Using an argument from authority, you can see that no compiler will actually optimize the calls to foo() and bar() out:

gcc versions 4.9.2, 5.3,or 6.1 with -O2:

```
foobar():
pushq   %rbx    
call    foo()    
movl    %eax, %ebx    
call    bar()    
testl   %ebx, %ebx    
cmove   %eax, %ebx    
movl    %ebx, %eax    
popq    %rbx    
ret
```

clang versions 3.7.1, or 3.8 with -O2:

```
foobar():                          
pushq   %rbx    
callq   foo()    
movl    %eax, %ebx    
callq   bar()    
testl   %ebx, %ebx    
cmovnel %ebx, %eax    
popq    %rbx
```

Comment: Well, my doubts are about the propagation function being `static inline` and having no side effects, so the compiler in this case *does* know what's happening inside. I just want to make sure, that all functions in the chain *will* get called, even if one of them returns an error. Making `rc_propagate` external will surely do the trick, but what about `static inline`? The later gives the compiler total knowledge about what's happening there.

Comment: @datenwolf They will be called even with static inline. Note: I mention that the external function is unknown, not the static one, and therefore the former must be called.